# Accessing Firebase Firestore on AWS Lambda

Tags: firebase, lambda, google-cloud-firestore

I have following problem

I am writing a lambda function which is gets a post value offer an API, than checks in firebase firestore if the value is there and than replies to the client. Simple.

This is my code:

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cors = require("cors")
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
var login = require("./test.json")

admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(login) })
const db = admin.firestore()

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    let result = req.body.code.toUpperCase()
    db.collection("voucher")
        .get()
        .then(x => {
            console.log("TEST")
            console.log(x)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).send({ err }))
})

module.exports.voucher = serverless(app)
```

The API works just fine, problem is connecting to the firestore, the error object I get always says:

```
{code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"}
```

I did it how it is shown in the tutorial here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

But it does not seem to work at all.

I downloaded the correct credentials, actually I gave myself admin access to everything. But still it does not work.

You guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-on-aws-lambda-4bf6d3a473d9) and see if it helps

Comment: Did you upload the node modules folder to lambda?